# Latex-Suite in Vim exits out of tex document if there's a warning in the aux file on compilation

Tags: filetype-tex

I recently installed Latex-Suite using Vundle, and I use Latex to take notes. My notes are separate files for each lecture, but I have a master.tex file set up to compile each document together, and I use the `subfile` packaged to do this. Unfortunately, this package can lead to some unavoidable warnings:

`Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document, using \AtBeginDocument instead.`

I believe this is a result of having multiple nested `\begin{document}` environments when the files are brought together. However, it does compile, and the document looks as it should. The problem is that Latex-Suite takes this warning and opens up the file `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty`, which I assume is where this warning presents. When it does this, it closes the current `.tex` file which I'm trying to edit, which is extremely annoying. My question is, did I set something up incorrectly with the way Latex-Suite compiles my documents, or is there a way to get this to stop happening. As a side-note, I am trying to get my final result in `.pdf` form for all of my compiled documents. Below are the relevant lines from my `.vimrc`:

> `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'`
>
> `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'`

This happens when I use the compile command `\lv` in Latex-Suite.

Also, this is my first post, please let me know if I've left anything important out.

Comment: Aside: you can hit `<C-^>` to get back to the original (or you should be able to)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, this does work, I did not know this command, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, as far as I could find that is the result of 2 things:

1. You are allowing `vim-latex` to jump to the first error atomatically. You can disable it with:

```
let g:Tex_GotoError=0
```

2. You are probably on Windows, and the jumping to the package file is the result of a misunderstanding in the file paths. You can fix that by adding to your vimrc:

```
set shellslash
```

This, however, creates a problem within `vim-latex` and the command `<Leader>ls`, to jump to the current position in your pdf stops working. The `<Leader>lv` command works properly. So is up to you to decide if this is adequate for your workflow.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the first bit worked! I'm on Mac so the second part didn't really apply, but thank you!